# JetBrains GoLand cannot find package 2020.2

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, goland

JetBrains GoLand cannot find package

project:
[image]

CreateUsers:
[image]

GOPATH
[image]

```
package main
    
import (
    "users"
)

func main() {
    println(CreateUser())

}
```

**CreateUser.go**

```
package users

func CreateUsers() string {
    return "user"
}
```

Comment: Please post actual code images.

Comment: the screenshot already clearly shows that ide does not pull up packages.

Comment: the screenshot already clearly shows that ide does not pull up packages.